# I'm getting Key Error message in Python for Foursquare API

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, foursquare, keyerror

I'm trying to use Foursquare API to get information on venues. I'm getting keyerror message using the code below.

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=1000, LIMIT=100):
    
    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)
            
        # create the API request URL
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, 
            CLIENT_SECRET, 
            VERSION, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            radius, 
            LIMIT)
            
        # make the GET request
        
        results = requests.get(url).json()['response'].get('groups',[{}])[0].get('items', [])
        
        # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
        venues_list.append([(
            name, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            v['venue']['name'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
            v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 
                  'Neighborhood Latitude', 
                  'Neighborhood Longitude', 
                  'Venue', 
                  'Venue Latitude', 
                  'Venue Longitude', 
                  'Venue Category']
    
    return(nearby_venues)

toronto_venues=getNearbyVenues(names=df['Neighborhood'],latitudes=df['Latitude'],longitudes=df['Longitude'])
```

KeyError: 'Neighborhood'

I have waited a couple of days to make sure I haven't gone over my limit and changed the Version and reset the client secret. I have also tried creating a new account but I'm still receiving this error message.

This is the dataframe

```
     Borough                Neighborhood            Latitude    Longitude
0   North York                           Parkwoods  43.753259   -79.329656
1   North York                    Victoria Village  43.725882   -79.315572
2   Downtown Toronto     Regent Park, Harbourfront  43.654260   -79.360636
3   North York     Lawrence Manor, Lawrence Heights 43.718518   -79.464763
4   Queen's Park      Ontario Provincial Government 43.662301   -79.389494
```

> ```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>    2645             try:
> -> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>    2647             except KeyError:
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Neighborhood'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-109-7784a05c5fcd> in <module>
> ----> 1 toronto_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=df['Neighborhood'],latitudes=df['Latitude'],longitudes=df['Longitude'])
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
>    2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
>    2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> -> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
>    2801             if is_integer(indexer):
>    2802                 indexer = [indexer]
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>    2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>    2647             except KeyError:
> -> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>    2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>    2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Neighborhood'
> ```

Comment: What does your `df` look like?

Comment: Also please post the full error traceback, not just the error phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by rewriting the codes into a new notebook.